# Bijection between groups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\{A\in M_{2\times2}(F_4)\colon \det A\not=0\}$ be a group and $Z(G)\subset G$. I am working on a project (lin.alg.) and I am curious if there is a mapping (injective and surjective) that maps $G/Z(G)$ to $Alt(5)$? Is this a known problem?

Comment: Yes there is and this is a somehow hard (not too much) but classical problem to show it...

Comment: Yes, the action of the group on the $5$ $1$-dimensional subspaces of $F_4^2$ ia a homomorphism from $G$ to $A_5$ in which the kernel consiss of the three scalar matrices. This is known as the *projective action*.